# Does API carries data or it is just data which is carried by something else?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm currently studying JavaScript for frontend development and want to know what exactly API is. I know that Public APIs exist which we can use by making API calls (through fetch, axios, etc.). I don't understand if it is a data(XML, JSON, etc) created by backend developers or it is mechanism which is carries that data(XML, JSON, etc). So my question is: **Does API carries data or it is just data which is carried by something else?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you ask for the transmission channel? Or who creates the data?

Comment: What research have you done before posting here...? API literally stands for *a*pplication *p*rogramming *i*nterface - ***interface*** being the most important word in this context.

Comment: The relationship an API has with the data it serves can take many forms. You can have a server hosting a Javascript json api that has on it the same SQL server that hosts the data it's serving, or it could be on a different server. The processes generating that data could be processed via that very same Javascript api, or there could be entirely unrelated processes generating the data. Everything is a possibility.

Comment: It depends. In many APIs I'd consider the format in which data is returned part of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An API *provides* data, and ways of manipulating data - The actual data might be hosted on the same server that exposes the API, or it might be hosted somewhere else, or the data might come from a different service altogether, behind the scenes.

The main point is that it's an *interface* for interacting with data, wherever that data may be.

As the consumer of an API, you don't care where the actual data is, how it's stored, or even what it's structure is - you simply use the interface that's provided for you.